# How to integrate my calculation C code with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am using a dual channels DAQ card with data stream mode. I wrote some code for analysis/calculation and put them to the main code for operation. However, the FIFO overflow warning sign always occur once its total data reach around 6000 MSamples (the DAQ on board memory is 8GB). I am well-noticed that a complicated calculation might retard the system and cause the overflow but all of the works I wrote are necessary to my experiment which means cannot be replaced (or there is more effective code can let me get the same result). I have heard that the OpenMP might be a solution to boost up the speed, but I am just a beginner in C, how could I implement to my calculation code?

My computer has 64GB RAM and Intel Core i7 processor. I always turn off other unnecessary software when running the data stream code. The code has been optimize as possible as I can, like simplify the `hilbert()` and use `memcpy` to pick out a specific range of data points.

This is how I process the data:

1.Install the FFTW source code for the Hilbert transform.
2.`For` loop to de-interleave `pi16Buffer` data to `ch2Buffer`
3.`memcpy` to get a certain range of data that I am interested put them to another array called `ch2newBuffer`
4.Do the `hilbert()` on `ch2newBuffer` and calculate its absolute number.
5.Find the max value of ch1 and `abs(hilbert(ch2newBuffer))`.
6.Calculate `max(abs(hilbert(ch2))) / max(ch1)`.

Here is a part of the my DAQ code which in charge to calculation:

```
void hilbert(const int16* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    //fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    int hN = N>>1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    //plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_backward);
    // do some cleaning
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
    //fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    //for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        //out[i][REAL] /= N;
        //out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    //}
}


float SumBufferData(void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits)
{
    // In this routine we sum up all the samples in the buffer. This function 
    // should be replaced with the user's analysys function


    if ( 8 == u32SampleBits )
    {
        pu8Buffer = (uInt8 *)pBuffer;
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++)
        {
            i64Sum += pu8Buffer[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pi16Buffer = (int16 *)pBuffer;
        
        
        
        fftw_complex(hilbertedch2[N]);
        fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, hilbertedch2, hilbertedch2, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_plan plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, hilbertedch2, hilbertedch2, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    
    
        
        ch2Buffer = (int16*)calloc(u32Size / 2, sizeof * ch2Buffer);
        ch2newBuffer= (int16*)calloc(u32Size/2, sizeof* ch2newBuffer);
        

        // De-interleave the data from pi16Buffer
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2 ; i++)
        {
            ch2Buffer[i] = pi16Buffer[i*2+1];

        }

        // Pick out the data points range that we are interested
        memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[6944], 1024 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));
        // Do the hilbert transform to these data points
        hilbert(ch2newBuffer, hilbertedch2, plan_forward, plan_backward);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);

        
        //Find max value in each segs of ch1 and ch2
        for (i = 128; i < 200 ; i++)
        {
            if (pi16Buffer[i*2] > max1)
                max1 = pi16Buffer[i*2];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            if (fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]) > max2)
                max2 = fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
        }
        
        Corrected = max2 / max1 / N; // Calculate the signal correction

        
        
    
        
        
    }
    free(ch2Buffer);
    free(ch2newBuffer);
    return Corrected;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, or your question?

Comment: Time for you to learn how to *profile* your code. And you can only do that on your own, with real data. There are several thousand tutorials on that topic alone, so just go ahead and pick one. Just remember, profile first, *then* start optimizing when you know what is slow at all.

Comment: 1D FFT doesn't run very efficiently in parallel, but you can run multiple 1D FFTs at the same time. You also seem to be constantly creating and destroying FFTW execution plans that could be created once and then reused multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Loop are typically a good start for parallelism, for instance:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    out[i][REAL] = in[i];
    out[i][IMAG] = 0;
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:max2)
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
     float tmp = fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
     max2 = (max2 > tmp) ? max2 : tmp.
}
```

That being said, you need to profile your code find out where the execution takes the most time and try to parallelized if possible. However, looking at what you have posted, I do not see a lot of parallelism opportunity there.

Comment: I think it is fine just point out which part can be used in OpenMP, Thanks!

Comment: @PsK Sorry, I did not get it, do you want to point out all the parts?